# mysqli_fetch_array() retrieves nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a simple database table "accounts" with 3 entries: 'user','pass', and 'ID'. The ID being an integer.

I'm trying to retrieve the ID from the table and store it into $_SESSION['id'], but I'm having no luck.

Here's the code:

```
session_start();  

// Checks to see if the input account is valid
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts 
 WHERE user='$_POST[user]'
 AND pass='$_POST[pass]'");

//Check to see if account exists
if(!mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
  }
else
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $id = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id['ID'];
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
  }

 //header('Location: index1.php/');

?>
```

Nothing is coming out of the echo $_SESSION['id']. I've tried to echo $id['ID'] itself and it does not work either.

On my index1.php page I do manage to retrieve the information with the same bit of code, except the $result does not use the WHERE and AND clauses for the select statement.

Comment: what do you get when you count the returned rows? mysqli_num_rows($result)

Comment: Please, before you do anything else, read up on [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and use `mysqli`'s [SQL placeholders feature](http://bobby-tables.com/php). What you're doing here demonstrates recklessly bad habits and will get you into serious trouble. You **cannot** put `$_POST` data into a query without escaping.

Comment: I'm aware of possible gaps in my coding, and I will read the link provided, but as of right now I'm trying to get the concept down before I dive too deep into protection issues.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: The problem with "protection issues" is that if you're not using placeholders, you'll have to find these later, and they can prove tricky to uncover. Missing even one is enough for someone to bust your site wide open and wreck it. You're making some gigantic mistakes that should be addressed before you make more of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually fetching the first two rows (each call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` gets you one line of the result), which is probably not what you want. Just fetch one time and reuse the result:

```
// ...

//Check to see if account exists
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(!$row)
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
  }
else
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['ID'];
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
  }
// ...
```

<sup>As mentioned in the comments, your code is wide open to SQL injections. Read up on prepared statements to prevent this or sanitize your variables manually (which is not recommended!).</sup>

Comment: Much appreciated. I was unaware that you could not fetch the data twice. This answers other questions I was having with this code as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are fetching the data twice: once in the `if` statement and once in the `else`. Consider using this:

```
//Check to see if account exists
if($id!=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
  }
else
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id['ID'];
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
  }
```

Or this:

```
//Check to see if account exists
if(!$result)
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
  }
else
  {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $id = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id['ID'];
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
  }
```